# Convert a project to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to open the following project https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android on Android Studio but all the things I try it give me errors related to gradle :s

It says version 0.9.0 introduce some incompatible changes but then I can't make the changes they said.

Can anyone try it to me?

Comment: No joke I've seen a lot of people saying manual copying into a new Android Studio project (yea as bad as it sounds) is the fix.

Comment: it looks like the solution :s I need to copy, /src, /res and manifest file, don't I?

Comment: No @metRo_, it's the Gradle build files you need. This is why you need to put it into Eclipse, then export and have Eclipse build the needed Gradle files, as it stands, it sounds like they aren't there.

Comment: @Blaine here we are talking about create a project on android studio and copy there the code.

Comment: That's my point. You CANT do that. You would have to `import` the project into Android Studio. AS uses Gradle. Eclipse does not. You have to export from Eclipse with the Gradle build files to import into AS

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue is that Android Studio uses Gradle and Eclipse does not. It sounds like the GitHub project was built with Eclipse, which means you first have to import that project into Eclipse, then export it with the Gradle files.

From the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

> **Export from Eclipse**
>   Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin (you must have version 22.0 or higher).
>   In Eclipse, select File > Export.
>   In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate Gradle build files.
>   Select the project you want to export for Android Studio and click Finish.
>   Your selected project remains in the same location but now contains a build.gradle file and is ready for Android Studio.
>
> **Import into Android Studio** In Android Studio, close any projects currently open. You should see the Welcome to Android Studio window.
>   Click Import Project. Locate the project you exported from Eclipse,
>   expand it, select the build.gradle file and click OK. In the following
>   dialog, leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK. (You do not
>   need to specify the Gradle home.) Now that your project is imported to
>   Android Studio, read Tips and Tricks for some help getting started.
>
> Note: It's possible to import an existing Android project to Android
>   Studio even if you don't generate a Gradle build file from
>   Eclipse—Android Studio will successfully build and run projects using
>   an existing Ant build file. However, in order to take advantage of
>   build variants and other advanced features in the future, we strongly
>   suggest that you generate a Gradle build file using the ADT plugin or
>   write your own Gradle build file for use with Android Studio. For more
>   information about the Gradle build system, see the Gradle Plugin User
>   Guide.

Comment: It doesn't work and doesn't even reflect the new version of android studio!

Comment: See edits. You have to import to Eclipse, then export to Android Studio.

Comment: I did that. Per example this option doesn't appear to me: "leave Use gradle wrapper selected and click OK"

Comment: @metRo_ you have to 1. take the gitHub code and IMPORT to Eclipse. Then 2. EXPORT and build Gradle files.

Comment: As I said before I that and it doesn't work, don't you mind to try out?

Comment: It worked for me. You need to export as a gradle build. Not an android project.

Comment: I format my PC with kubuntu some days ago. Today I install Android studio and ADT Eclipse. Did a hello world with Android Studio and it is ok. Load a project on eclipse run and it works like before. Export then import and the result is: http://i.imgur.com/0h2ZCGy.png

Comment: You don't import the Eclipse project, you import the `build.gradle` file. Read the instructions that I posted.